# Какой автономный сервер с большой памятью данных, для Unity игры на смартфоны, с жанром Idle, будет самым актуальным? (подробности игры в описании)

Tags: c#, unity3d, сервер, память

Рассматриваю создание простой игры, с **системой Pay-To-Win**. Ближайший пример, **Idle игра**, где тебе надо будет нажать "в бой", и игра сама проведёт его, и покажет тебе результат. Будет таблица лидеров, создание предметов, их заточка, и выпадение с монстров случайных предметов.

Выше перечисленное, и другие взаимодействия, **по скорости сопоставимые с ККИ** (2-5 запроса в секунду на сервер, в самом загруженном случае. Это не FPS, где запросов будет более 15-60 на сервер) Проведение атаки, просчёт урона и предметы игрока. **Все важные данные будут на сервере**, весь просчёт также на нём, потом готовый результат по запросу, отправит на смартфон игрока.

Какой сервер самый актуальный для такой игры? Перечислю хостов серверов, которых знаю, и что сейчас думаю о выборе их:

**Photon** — Хороший выбор для начальных проектов, но вероятно именно сессионных игр. В нём маловато возможность просмотреть метрики игроков, и хранение данных в нём сложнее (Не успел разобраться, может это не так)

**PlayFab** — Хост поддерживаемый от Microsoft, в общем по моему, то что нужно. В нём много метрик (в будущем может пригодиться, для проверки популярности покупок, или часто используемой экипировки), и есть возможность просто хранить данные на сервере, и с этим работать (стоит отметить, что видео о том, как им пользоваться, тоже очень много). Но не знаю, есть ли подводные камни, или какие-то проблемы в его использовании. Видео на эту тему найти не смог.

**Google VM, Amazon AWS** и т.д. — почти все хосты, которые изначально не настроены под Unity, использовать не хочется. Раз уж начал делать донатную игру с простой механикой, то разбираться в том, как почти с нуля настроить серверную экосистему, меня совершенно не интересует (вероятно это наиболее эффективные варианты, хоть настройка вручную, но дешевле и стабильнее. Тем не менее, если это так, я лучше создам на простой основе через иных хостов сервера. А позднее перейду на более сложный этап, но точно не сейчас). Если только в них нет каких-то плюсов, которых не заметил

Быстро подведу итог, вообще никогда не пользовался такими сервисами, и не хостил сервера. А проанализировал эти варианты, буквально вчера вечером. Вопросов много, времени не очень. В любом случае, спасибо что прочитали, или благодарю за ответы. На данный момент, это самый сложный для меня вопрос, буду очень признателен за любую помощь

Comment: Как заработать денег почти ничего не делая и ничего не потратив? Никак. Нет времени - наймите второго Unity-разработчика в команду, который шарит и сделает вам хороший сервер. Поверьте, выбор площадки для хостинга - такая мелочь, что она растворится на фоне других вопросов, когда вы перейдете от рассуждений к практике. При этом совершенно не важно, что именно вы выберете. На этот вопрос невозможно дать объективный ответ.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, на самом деле полезный (сам слышал о большом количестве начинающих программистов, с первого проекта выбирающих ММО-РПГ нового поколения, без опыта, команды, наставника, или хотя-бы денег).

Уверенность в своих силах у меня есть, уже 3 с половиной года программировал, и помощник в программирование, и по совместительству дизайнер тоже есть. Когда выбираю наиболее простой вариант, есть желание лишь запустить проект, и проверить MVP как можно раньше. Ведь есть большая вероятность, что проект не взлетит, а потратить время и деньги можно большие.

Comment: Если проект на самом деле получиться дельный, то буду рассматривать долгосрочную поддержу. С упором на труд и выгоду, а не скорость и тестирование. Если нет (такое вполне вероятно. Если бы такие игры постоянно взлетали по популярности, то не думаю, что люди кроме таких проектов что-то ещё программировали), то оставлю проект на портфолио, и буду делать игр на мобильные устройства, возможно больше не доходя до темы поддержки сервера (плюс минус, через готовый интерфейс компании, или их IDE/библиотека/Фреймворк. Где свой софт поддерживать не нужно будет)

Comment: Вы же наметили себе цель пилить серьезные решения, вот и выбирайте наиболее гибкую для этого платформу, логично? Если даже она скушает какую-то лишнюю часть вашего времени, разве затраты на изучение не окупятся в будущем?

Comment: Есть еще один немаловажный фактор - обстановка в мире. В свете повесточки я бы выбирал ту конфигурацию сервера, которую можно унести куда угодно в случае чего. Известно, что компании-гиганты могут щелчком пальца устроить апокалипсис всем своим хостам, как это происходит сейчас в медиа-сфере. Уничтожают всё без разбору. Это конечно не значит, что вам следует всё обдумать заново при выборе хостинг-провайдера, а хотя-бы держать это в уме. Хз, что будет дальше, с каждым днём всё становится интереснее и интереснее. Реплики, бэкапы, портативность.